# Open pdf in react-native using url

Tags: react-native

I am using [react-native-pdf-view](https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-pdf-view) library to display pdf in react-native.Following is the render method of the component.

```
  return <PDFView ref={(pdf)=>{this.pdfView = pdf;}}
     path={"http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf"}
     onLoadComplete = {(pageCount)=>{
        this.pdfView.setNativeProps({
            zoom: 1.5
        });
     }}
     style={styles.pdf}/>
```

But this throws the following error:

[image: Error]

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong or suggest some other way to open pdf(using url) in react-native.

P.S. I am creating android app on ubuntu.

Comment: You should return PDFView from render method.
render(){
  return(  
           <PDFView ...............
   );
}

Comment: @Harish_N Sorry about that but I am getting a different error now.

Comment: @Harish_N What error do you have now?